# Better Understanding Badges

Tags: discussion, badges

There are a couple of Badges that i do not understand the explanation they have on how to obtain them. For example:

**Epic Badge (Silver)** - Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days

Does that mean that i need to get 200 reputation in 50 days? How is that possible?

**Legendary Badge (Gold)** - Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days

If Epic Badge was tough i think Legendary is for Chuck Norris. Mortarboard (Bronze) is more logical than this two. The way i understand it is that i need to obtain 200 reputation everyday for 50 days (Epic Badge) and 200 rep for 150 days (Epic Badge). Is this correct? Or is it that i need to get 200 reputation in a 50 days time and 200 rep in a 150 days time? Sorry for the lack of understanding of this two.

**Tenacious (Silver)** - Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total

**Unsung Hero (Gold)** - Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

**Electorate (Gold)** - Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

Did NOT understand anything about this last two. I mean WHAT??

Comment: Chuck Norris indeed. XD

Comment: It does not need to be consecutive days.

Comment: So it can be in any days but you need to accumulate 50 days with 200 rep? and 150 with 200 rep?. That sounds more human to me.

Comment: Added the last 2 I did not even closely understand

Comment: Added Electorate since what the hell is "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions". So I have to vote on 600 questions but 25% of those votes have to be on questions... HUH?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to earn at least 200 rep. on *each of* 50 / 150 days to get Epic and Legendary.

For Tenacious and Unsung Hero, you need at least 5 / 10 accepted answers with no upvotes on them, and these Accepted answers without upvotes have to make up at least 20% / 25% of all your answers.

Comment: Added 2 more if you could give a helping hand with them.

Comment: at first even i thought it was on consecutive days .

Answer (score 0):

Zero scores, if I understand right, is answers without upvotes or downvotes. If 5 to 20% of your *accepted* answers are have no up or downvotes you get the Tenacious badge. Likewise, if 10 t0 25% of your accepted answers have received no love you get the Unsung Hero badge.

Comment: Gah, I are too late.

Answer (score 0):

On [general meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66749/have-i-misunderstood-tenacious) there are many such discussions, and they are better suited there, imho, because the badges-system is common for all sites, afaik, and not related to ubuntu especially.
And SO-meta is to my knowledge the right place for those common questions (but moderators don't seem to care much about it, leading to duplicated discussions in all meta places).

#### Moderators! Are you trying to collect many questions in meta?

If you follow the linked discussion, you will find that it is a common sport to upvote unupvoted questions, when somebody is complaining about not getting the badge. ;) So I will look now what I can do for you.

Answer (score 0):

In [a recent blog post on badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/), Jeff wrote:

> Badges are supposed to be a little mysterious; you should view them as minor puzzles with obvious hints.

Comment: haha!. I ok got it ;)