# Badges descriptions should be rewritten

Tags: discussion, badges

Taking this as base: [Better Understanding Badges](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1441/better-understanding-badges)

many badges descriptions should be rewritten for the user to understand them better. There are a lot that can be understood in several ways and if they are interpreted wrongly then they are not very helpful descriptions.

If anybody reads them all at the end you would have a hard time understanding many of them.

Maybe this is just me but I feel there is a little more work to be done on that part.

Comment: Can you give some examples of rewrites? I honestly don't find them hard to understand, so I'm not sure of how they should be rewritten.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is intentional. See this recent blog post, [A Bevy of New Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/):

> Badges are supposed to be a little mysterious; you should view them as minor puzzles with obvious hints.